# Switch password/fingerprint authentication on lid behaviour

Tags: ubuntu, login, pam, authentication

I set the fingerprint authentication as default for login and sudo commands. On 3 failures or no fingerprint detection for 10 seconds, password auth is required. When working with lid closed (external display), fingerprint sensor is blocked (physically) and I don't want to have to wait 10 seconds each time before password is asked. Is there a way to implement a change on type of auth depending on lid status.

Now using
Ubuntu 20.04 / Gnome
Fingerprint sensor: 138a:0097 Validity Sensors (Thinkpad T470)

[UPDATE]

```
santiago@thinkpad-t470 $ cat  /etc/pam.d/common-auth 
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block) auth   [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_fprintd.so max_tries=1 timeout=10
# debug auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around auth   required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block) auth   optional            pam_cap.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`?

Comment: Edited question with update. The whole file is commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Ubuntu, but you should be able to do it by changing timeout values inside `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`.

Try this (with escalated privileges):

```bsh
echo "auth  [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_fprintd.so max_tries=1 timeout=3" >> /etc/pam.d/common-auth
```

The timer is now set to three seconds. You can, of course, change that value to whatever you want.

If, for some reason, it doesn't work, edit the file with the following:

```bsh
    auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_fprintd.so max_tries=1 timeout=3
    auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
    auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
    auth    required            pam_permit.so
```

Comment: It does not change the auth behaviour on lid status but it's a solution. Works.

Comment: I know there were issues with `fprintd-pam` before, in which it wasn't possible to have *both* password *and* fingerprint to authenticate. That seems to may have changed, since doing a quick `cat /usr/share/doc/fprintd-pam/README` gives a different `Known issues` section than what it used to. Since you have a ThinkPad, you might be lucky; check out the [man pages pam_thinkfinger](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_thinkfinger) for more info. If that doesn't help, you can try making a new thread to see if someone can help you out.